# How to convert widget to widget??

Tags: flutter, dart, router, flutter-web, navigator

the handlerFunc wants to widget? but i have widget. And i have an error : The argument type 'SplashScreen Function(BuildContext, Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget? Function(BuildContext?, Map<String, List>)'.

```html
class Flurouter {
  static final FluroRouter router = FluroRouter();

  static final Handler _splashHandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          SplashScreen());

  static final Handler _mainHandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          LandingPage(
            page: params['name'][0],
            extra: '',
          )); // this one is for one paramter passing...

  // lets create for two parameters tooo...
  static final Handler _mainHandler2 = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          LandingPage(
            page: params['name'][0],
            extra: params['extra'][0],
          ));

  // ok its all set now .....
  // now lets have a handler for passing parameter tooo....

  static void setupRouter() {
    router.define(
      '/',
      handler: _splashHandler,
    );
    router.define(
      '/main/:name',
      handler: _mainHandler,
      transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    );

    router.define(
      '/main/:name/:extra',
      handler: _mainHandler2,
      transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `SplashScreen Function(BuildContext, Map<String, dynamic>)` is incompatible with `Widget? Function(BuildContext?, Map<String, List>)` because the latter expects to be able to pass `null` for the `BuildContext`, but the former requires it to be non-nullable.  The different return types don't matter since a function that returns a `SplashScreen` satisfies the contract of returning a `Widget?`.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I can't convert the widget. But I can ensure null safety like this:

```html
class Flurouter {
  static final FluroRouter router = FluroRouter();

  //Handlers setup here Where will I go?

  //parameterless redirects
  static final Handler _splashHandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    return const SplashScreen();
  });

  // one parameter redirects if you add extra thing
  static final Handler _mainHandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    return LandingPage(
      page: params['name'][0],
      extra: '',
    );
  });

  

  static void setupRouter() {
    router.define('/', handler: _splashHandler);
    router.define('/:name', handler: _mainHandler);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).